Fetching mergedpeaks for 3 samples with GenomicRanges and ChIPPeakAnno
I would be grateful with some help regarding extracting overlapping peaks with 3 peak-sets.
So here is my code
    #loading IP 

Abed <- import.bed("Apeaks.bed")
Abed
Abed$name <- paste("Abed", 1:length(Abed), sep = "")
Abed
"GRanges object with 85069 ranges and 1 metadata column:
          seqnames            ranges strand |        name
             <Rle>         <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>
      [1]     chr1     888281-888795      * |       Abed1
      [2]     chr1     912489-912699      * |       Abed2
      [3]     chr1     931707-931990      * |       Abed3
      [4]     chr1     940894-941141      * |       Abed4
      [5]     chr1     959148-959401      * |       Abed5
      ...      ...               ...    ... .         ...
  [85065]     chrY 15460814-15461309      * |   Abed85065
  [85066]     chrY 15462263-15462591      * |   Abed85066
  [85067]     chrY 15491520-15491757      * |   Abed85067
  [85068]     chrY 15591795-15592053      * |   Abed85068
  [85069]     chrY 19067572-19067997      * |   Abed85069"

#loading IP 

Bbed <- import.bed("Bpeaks.bed")
Bbed
Bbed$name <- paste("Bbed", 1:length(Bbed), sep = "")
Bbed
"GRanges object with 56273 ranges and 1 metadata column:
          seqnames            ranges strand |        name
             <Rle>         <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>
      [1]     chr1     778670-778900      * |       Bbed1
      [2]     chr1     888314-888844      * |       Bbed2
      [3]     chr1     906813-907046      * |       Bbed3
      [4]     chr1     931717-932033      * |       Bbed4
      [5]     chr1     959120-959385      * |       Bbed5
      ...      ...               ...    ... .         ...
  [56269]     chrY 17071142-17071368      * |   Bbed56269
  [56270]     chrY 17078839-17079100      * |   Bbed56270
  [56271]     chrY 17080163-17080381      * |   Bbed56271
  [56272]     chrY 17084542-17084736      * |   Bbed56272
  [56273]     chrY 19067639-19067958      * |   Bbed56273"

#loading IP 

Cbed <- import.bed("Cpeaks.bed")
Cbed
Cbed$name <- paste("Cbed", 1:length(Cbed), sep = "")
Cbed
"GRanges object with 18413 ranges and 1 metadata column:
          seqnames              ranges strand |        name
             <Rle>           <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>
      [1]     chr1       778622-778896      * |       Cbed1
      [2]     chr1       817295-817493      * |       Cbed2
      [3]     chr1       888351-888784      * |       Cbed3
      [4]     chr1     1000655-1001013      * |       Cbed4
      [5]     chr1     1375211-1375608      * |       Cbed5
      ...      ...                 ...    ... .         ...
  [18409]     chrX 154076464-154076652      * |   Cbed18409
  [18410]     chrX 154604080-154604321      * |   Cbed18410
  [18411]     chrX 155334844-155335237      * |   Cbed18411
  [18412]     chrY   12904889-12905202      * |   Cbed18412
  [18413]     chrY   14641712-14642108      * |   Cbed18413"

cobound_ABC <- findOverlapsOfPeaks(Abed, Bbed, Cbed, maxgap = 0, connectedPeaks = "keepAll")


cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks <- cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks$mergedPeaks
cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks
"GRanges object with 47790 ranges and 1 metadata column:
          seqnames              ranges strand |                           peakNames
             <Rle>           <IRanges>  <Rle> |                     <CharacterList>
      [1]     chr1       778622-778900      * |             Cbed__00001,Bbed__00001
      [2]     chr1     1574281-1574631      * |             Cbed__00006,Bbed__00009
      [3]     chr1   10429860-10430066      * |             Cbed__00064,Bbed__00162
      [4]     chr1   16623395-16623588      * |             Cbed__00112,Bbed__00304
      [5]     chr1   16644521-16644830      * |             Bbed__00305,Cbed__00113
      ...      ...                 ...    ... .                                 ...
  [47786]     chrX 153708365-153708741      * | Cbed__18407,Abed__85003,Bbed__56228
  [47787]     chrX 154604080-154604364      * | Cbed__18410,Bbed__56239,Abed__85020
  [47788]     chrX 155334844-155335266      * | Cbed__18411,Bbed__56248,Abed__85036
  [47789]     chrY   12904803-12905216      * | Abed__85048,Cbed__18412,Bbed__56257
  [47790]     chrY   14641589-14642108      * | Abed__85056,Bbed__56262,Cbed__18413
  -------
  seqinfo: 24 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths"

How do I keep only those merged peaks which have all three peak sets - Abed, Bbed and Cbed? When I export merged peaks I get all possible combinations. I tried to grepl it, but it is not working for GRanges object.
Thanks

I tried this and it works. If somebody has a cleaner idea, would be happy to know:
peak_names <- paste(cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks$peakNames, collapse = ",")
head(peak_names)
mergedpeaksdf <- data.frame(peak_names)
cobound_PIB_mergedPeaks$names <- peak_names

cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks_df <- data.frame(cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks)
cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks_df <- cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks_df[, -6] #remove peakNames list from GRanges

export.bed(cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks, "OverlappedMergedPeaks_ABC.HDF.bed")

write.table(cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks_df, "OverlappedMergedPeaks_ABC.HDF.txt", sep= "\t", quote = F)

# Extract peaks with "Abed", "Bbed", and "Cbed" in their names
desired_peaks <- subset(cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks_df, grepl("Abed",cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks_df$names) & grepl("Bbed", cobound_Bbed_mergedPeaks_df$names) & grepl("Cbed", cobound_ABC_mergedPeaks_df$names))

# Show the extracted peaks
dim(desired_peaks) #[1] 14947     6
write.table(desired_peaks, "OverlappedMergedPeaks_transformed.HDF-coboundABC.txt", sep= "\t", quote = F)

